# Informatica: wrong odbc.ini file referred by Workflow mappings

Tags: sql-server, odbc, informatica, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to execute a workflow mapping from within Informatica Workflow. The source being `MSSQL Server` and target `Oracle DB`. The mapping alike every other mapping seems to be referring to the system's `/etc/odbc.ini` file rather than the one sitting in `$INFA_HOME/ODBC7.1/odbc.ini`.

I've tried checking everything but can't seem to understand how this linking is getting established. I did many hit & trials to confirm which `odbc.ini` was getting referred and it was always the one sitting under `/etc/`. The `bash_profile's` variable `ODBCINI` is also pointing towards the `INFA_HOME` location.

Can someone shed some light on how or why the system's `odbc.ini` is getting referred. Any idea on how is it linked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to set two odbc related parameters in unix/linux users bash profile.

```
INFA_HOME=/opt/infa
ODBCINI= $INFA_HOME/ODBC7.1/odbc.ini
ODBCINST=$INFA_HOME/ODBC7.1/odbcinst.ini
```

Now, i feel like, your unix/linux user is not able to reach this location or they arent getting exported properly.
Login using the unix/linux user thats running informatica.

Then use `more $ODBCINI` to see if it has read permission.
Do same for ODBCINST.
Use `ssgodbc` tool to check connectivity to your mssql server DB.