# Informatica Power Centre workflow manager

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am trying to load data from source to target in informatica but I am getting error when I start workflow:-
[workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DD22.png)
error1:-

> Severity   Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
> INFO    01-09-2022 6.12.46 PM   node01  MAPPING DBG_21349   No load constraints for Target [target_info]. It does not reference any primary table from the same active source or transaction generator.

error2-

> Severity   Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
> ERROR   01-09-2022 6.12.46 PM   node01  PRE-SESS    CMN_1022    Database driver error...
> CMN_1022 [
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
> Database driver error...
> Function Name : Connect
> Database driver error...
> Function Name : Connect
> Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [dbc] and connection string [].]

I am not able to understand , its a ODBC connection error or mapping level issue.
please help me to solve this.
I am sharing screenshot of the error log also.

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETbHW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup ODBC connection information. As per session log, i do not see proper connection info set for target. Session failed when it is trying to connect to target DB.

1. To set ODBC, you need to first setup odbc.ini file located at `$INFA_HOME/ODBC7.1/odbc.ini`. You need to enter details like host/port/db name in proper format. Name the connection to mytarget(or whatever you prefer).
   how to set this up can be found in this link -
   [Informatica: wrong odbc.ini file referred by Workflow mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222796/informatica-wrong-odbc-ini-file-referred-by-workflow-mappings/69224387#69224387)
2. Create new informatica connection of type ODBC(name it as myconnection). Supply user/password and mytarget as connection string.
   [image: ![conn info]
3. in the session, set this target to this connection object myconnection.